# (Sequencia IJ 4) Por que meu código em Python está dando Runtime error no URI Online Judge?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu consegui rodar o programa em meu computador, no entanto, quando submeto para os casos de teste online ele acusa 'Runtime error' e não estou conseguindo contornar o erro.

O problema é o (Sequencia IJ 4), o link: 
https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1098

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu último código submetido encontra-se abaixo

```
# Name of the problem: Sequencia IJ 4
# Link: https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1098

import numpy

for i in numpy.arange(0.0, 2.2, 0.2):
  for j in range(1, 4):

    i_print = round(i,1)
    i_print = str(i_print)
    i_int, i_dec = i_print.split(".")

    j_print = round(j+i,1)
    j_print = str(j_print)
    j_int, j_dec = j_print.split(".")

    if(i_dec == '0'):
            print('I='+i_int, end = " ")
    else:
            print('I='+i_int+'.'+i_dec, end = " ")

    if(j_dec == '0'):
            print('J='+j_int)
    else:
            print('J='+j_int+'.'+j_dec)
```

Comment: Isso acontece por que durante o tempo de execução alguma exception está sendo levantada. Já tentou testar todos os casos do uDebug? Ademais, sua solução parece pouco performática, visto a simplicidade do problema... Tente dar uma olhada melhor na lógica que deverá construir! Se conseguir levantar a exception, atualize o post aqui.

Comment: Não existem casos de teste neste problema. Só é imprimir a sequência lógica corretamente na hora que você colocar o código para rodar. Um cara no facebook me mostrou o código que ele tinha feito pro mesmo problema (também deu Runtime Error aqui), perguntei para ele para ver se o código dele (https://bitbucket.org/galego/uri_online_judge_python/src/master/iniciante/1098_sequencia_ij_4_solucao_2.py?fbclid=IwAR01PgUxH-OkoONlrikcEdURM_9aADnAnUFYmxvNqolfRaBqpXgXzgSnceM) foi aceito. A plataforma do URI pode estar com algum problema, não sei ... uma suposição.

Comment: Essa pergunta não faz sentido e você literalmente precisa de uma bola de cristal para adicionar qual é exatamente a saída que ele espera. Provavelmente o erro se dá por estar utilizando a biblioteca NumPy e a plataforma não possuir ela disponível.

Comment: Eu não consegui entender o motivo do Runtime Error, provavelmente deve ser o uso da biblioteca NumPy mesmo. Em relação ao problema, um cara no Facebook me ajudou a encontrar uma solução utilizando a biblioteca Decimal (a desconhecia, por estar iniciando agora no Python). 

Já resolvi o problema, irei responder a minha própria pergunta para acrescentar uma resposta aqui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta questão se refere ao problema de número **"1098"**, cujo título é **"Sequência IJ 4"**, disponibilizado por **Uri Online Judge** (Maratona Online de Programação).

[Veja aqui](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1098) a íntegra do enunciado.

Nesta questão, pede-se para criar um programa que apresente a sequência conforme o `exemplo` apresentado.

Para resolver esta questão podemos utilizar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
# Número do problema: 1098
# Título do problema: Sequência IJ 4
# Categoria: Iniciante
# Disponibilizado por: https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1098

i = 0
j = 1
acrescimo = (0.2)
n = 0
while i <= 2:
    for c in range(1, 4):
        if i > 2.19:
            print('I={:.0f} J={:.0f}'.format(2, j))
        if i == 1.0 or i == 0.0 or i > 1.8:
            print('I={:.0f} J={:.0f}'.format(i, j))
        elif i < 2:
            print('I={:.1f} J={:.1f}'.format(i, j))
        j = j + 1
    i = i + acrescimo
    j = 1 + i
```

Veja o funcionamento do algoritmo no [repl.it](https://repl.it/join/ygbgevmc-solkarped).

Este algoritmo já foi `testado`, `submetido` e devidamente `aprovado` no site `Uri`, sob linguagem de programação **Python 3**.